# Printing stars with Java. I am stuck

Tags: java

I'm working on with a problem where I should print stars (`*`) with Java. Here's the pattern that program should print: There should be three lines of stars

Line 1. 5 Stars.
Line 2. 3 Stars.
Line 3. 9 Stars.

Here's what I have a drafted so far:

```java
private static void printStars(int number) {
  System.out.print("*");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printStars(5);
    printStars(3);
    printStars(9);
}
```

Comment: You should look at some introductory programming guides, especially ones that explain loops.

Comment: In your `printStars` method, you need to use a loop to print the number of stars you want, and then after the loop print a newline so the next call to `printStars` will be on a separate line

Comment: Tutorial page for java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/  Consider reading the tutoria named "Learning the Java Language"

Comment: You just forget a for loop :)

Comment: I don't see the need for the downvotes - sure it's basic, but there's at least some effort that's gone into writing the code so far... as far as basic questions go this is one of the better ones!

Comment: Everyone likes loops... It could be done with recursion also. :)

Answer (score 2):

```
private static void printStars(int number) {
    System.out.print("*");
}
```

This method requires a loop to print the required number of stars, rather than just one (which is what you're doing at the moment, ignoring the parameter that's passed in.) Look up "for loops" - that's in all likelihood what you're required to use here.

Comment: you'll need to print a newline character at the end of each loop